# getting pythons __set__ working

Tags: python, python-2.7, descriptor, magic-methods

I just wanted to use the descriptor pattern, but it didn't seem to work that well.
Here is a short example (without any real use, just to show):

```
class Num(object):
  def__init__(self, val=0):
    self.val = val
  def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    return self.val
  def __set__(self, instance, val):
    self.val = val
  def __str__(self):
    return "Num(%s)" % self.val
  def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()

class Test(object):
  def __init__(self, num=Num()):
    self.num = num
```

and the Test:

```
>>>t = Test()
>>>t.num # OK
Num(0)
>>>t.num + 3 #OK i know how to fix that, but I thought __get__.(t.num, t, Test) will be called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Num' and 'int'
>>> t.num = 4 # why isn't __set__(t.num, t, 4) called here?
>>> t.num
4
```

What is my misconception here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Descriptors only work when they are attributes of a class, not an instance.  If you change your class to:

```
class Test(object):
    num = Num()
```

. . . then the descriptor will work.

However, because the descriptor has to be set on the class, that means there is only one instance of the descriptor, so it's probably not a good idea for the descriptor to store its values on `self`.  Such values will be shared across all instances of the class.  Instead, set the value on `instance`.

Also, note that your `__str__` and `__repr__` will probably not do what you think they will.  Calling `t.num` will activate the descriptor and return its `val`, so the result of `t.num` will be the plain number 0, not a `Num` instance.  The whole point of the descriptor is to transparently return the result of `__get__` without making the descriptor object itself visible.

Here are some illustrative examples:

```
>>> t1 = Test()
>>> t2 = Test()
>>> t1.num
0
>>> Test.num
0
# Accessing the descriptor object itself
>>> Test.__dict__['num']
Num(0)
>>> t1.num = 10
>>> t1.num
10
# setting the value changed it everywhere
>>> t2.num
10
>>> Test.num
10
```

With an alternate version of the descriptor:

```
class Num(object):
  def __init__(self, val=0):
    self.val = val

  def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    try:
        return instance._hidden_val
    except AttributeError:
        # use self.val as default
        return self.val

  def __set__(self, instance, val):
    instance._hidden_val = val

class Test(object):
    num = Num()

>>> t1 = Test()
>>> t2 = Test()
>>> t1.num
0
>>> t1.num = 10
>>> t1.num
10
# Now there is a separate value per instance
>>> t2.num
0
```

Comment: Thx, for the hint with classattribute. I just missed that detail. if repr(t.num) will not work as expected, at least t.num + 3 will work as expected, which is what I wanted in my real use case

Answer (score 0):

As BrenBarn stated Descriptors appear to be for Class variables. You might be interested in looking at Pythons properties.

```
class GenericItem(object):
    """Generic item descriptor"""

    def __init__(self, value=None, name=""):
        super().__init__()

        self.value = value
        self.name = name
    # end Constructor

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
#         print(self, obj, objtype)
        return self.value
    # end __get__

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
#         print(self, obj, value)
        self.value = value
    # end __set__

    def __str__(self):
        if self.name is None or self.name == "":
            return str(self.value)
        return self.name +"("+str(self.value)+")"
    # end __str__
# end class Num

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        super().__init__()

        self._num = GenericItem(value, "Number")
    # end Constructor

    @property
    def num(self):
        """This is a number"""
        return self._num
    @num.setter
    def num(self, value):
        self._num.__set__(None, value)
    # end num property
# end class Test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = GenericItem(1, "Generic")
    print(g)
    g = 5
    print(g)


    t = Test()
    print(t.num)
    try:
        t.num + 3 # We didn't implement any sort of addition __add__
    except:
        pass
    t.num = 4
    print(t.num)
```

Result:

```
Generic(1)
5
Number(0)
Number(4)
```

Properties help control how instance variables are set.